# How can I stream only NEW tweets with tweepy

Tags: python, twitter, bots, streaming, tweepy

I am trying to create my first Twitter bot using Python.
Its job is to check twitter for new tweets that meet a certain condition, and then to retweet that post.

However, the program keeps finding old posts that meet that condition, but I'm only interested in tweets posted AFTER the bot starts.

Is there something I can do about this?

Comment: Check tweet creation timestamp to be greater then bot start timestamp. There should be also an option to set "from_date".

Comment: I've not found such option. I'm still looking. Thank you.

Answer (score 1):

Streaming with Twitter API v1.1 or v2 will *only* return new real-time Tweets.

Answer (score 0):

I found a way to do this.

1a. I used datetime module to get my current system time
1b. I converted this to a string and pulled only the date and time
2a. I collected the tweet timestamp for each tweet "tweet.created_at"
2b. I converted this to a string and pulled only the date and time
3.  For each tweet that was found by Stream service, I checked to see if it was older than my current date.
4. If it was, I skipped it and went to the next.

From my search, I think this is the only way to do this.